# Symfony, ManyToMany setters and getters in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have little problem with ManyToMany setters and getters

Company.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="companies")
*/
protected $employees;
```

User.php

```
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="employees")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    */
protected $companies;
```

then in Controller I try set user value into company

```
$company->setEmployees($company->getEmployees($user));
```

I keep getting

> "Attempted to call an undefined method named "setEmployees" of class
>   ..\Entity\Company". Did you mean to call e.g. "addEmployees" or
>   "getEmployees"?

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Did you define the "public function getEmployees ..." and "public function setEmployees.." methods in the User's class?

Comment: Just to point out that this operation seems pretty useless, because you set to your company the users it already has ...

Comment: You are **adding** an employee to an array of employees belonging to a company so you should use `addEmployee` (or `addEmployees` in your case) rather than setting an employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of your ManyToMany relation between your two entities. By default, the getters & setters will become `setEmployee()`(singular, because it is used to add a single Employee object) and `addEmployees()` (plural, because it is used to add an array of Employees). Check out if everything is spelled correctly and respects this principle.

Given that `$user`seems to be a singular user, I'd make the following change :

```
$company->setEmployee($company->getEmployees($user));
```

Hope this helps.